# Mongoose - constructing an AND query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose query that does a GEO polygon search:

```
Location.find({
    "location.coordinates": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    coords
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}, cb);
```

I now wish to limit the search results that contain a "rating" property = 5, so effectively an AND i.e. the geo search AND a rating of 5.

Can anyone advise how I would construct the query to combine the GEO search AND a rating property?

Comment: All queries in MongoDB are implictly an "and" statement by default. There is an `$and` operator but it is usually only needed for multiple conditions on the "same" field, or more complex nestings. You should just be able to add the condition. Is you question really "how does this work alongside geolocation?"

Comment: @NeilLunn - many thanks - im new to Mongo so adding the condition as you suggested is ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NeilLunn and @bearrito for guidance. I can simply place the criteria as a parent criteria:

```
    Location.find({
    "rating": 5,
    "location.coordinates": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    coords
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},cb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following achieves what you want assuming that the ratings field is at the top-level of your document

```
Location.find({
"$and" : [      
         {"location.coordinates": {
          "$geoWithin": {
           "$geometry": { "type": "Polygon","coordinates": [coords] } }
           }
         },
         {"ratings" : 5}
         ]

}, cb);
```

Comment: Very unnecessary since just adding the "ratings" field at the top level of `.find()` does the same thing. All query arguments in MongoDB are an "and" operation by default.

Comment: Very necessary since I don't know much else about his schema and it is the safest answer I could provide given the lack of other information. Obviously javascript doesn't allows for duplicate keys so "$and" is really only necessary for expressing multiple operators on the same field.